# cakephp 2.0 missing controller

Tags: controller, cakephp-2.0

I am getting the following error and am not really sure why. I really don't even know where to look. All my paths seem to be working ok.

Any suggestions as to where I should look?
version 2.0.4

thanks!

[Controller Error http://img1.UploadScreenshot.com/images/orig/12/33811143574-orig.png](http://img1.UploadScreenshot.com/images/orig/12/33811143574-orig.png)

Comment: what is the url you are accessing?

Comment: It does not matter what url is used.

Comment: then it's a route issue.

Comment: @Mahesh I have not changed anything in the routes.php file. Could it be somewhere else? I have made very few changes. The console skeleton was used for the default config. Version 2.0.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have determined the issue. In my previous versions of cake 1.3 I modified the ROOT and APP_PATH directories so that I could point the browser to **path_to_myapp/app/** instead of just **path_to_myapp**. So when I tried to do the same thing out of habit, it understandably did not work. Thank you for your help.

This is my modified index file if anyone is interested in loading it in a similar way. It should also be noted that I have a special CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH.

```
    if (!defined('ROOT')) {
        define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
    }


    if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
    define('APP_DIR', '');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your /app/config/routes.php file is including the CakePHP default routes file.

```
/**
 * Load the CakePHP default routes. Remove this if you do not want to use
 * the built-in default routes.
 */
    require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

You should have that at the end of your routes.php file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I believe this piece of code comes stock with the app. It is in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue that drove me nuts for way too long. I had a typo in the file name for my controller. For example, `ApplesController.php` was actually `[space]ApplesController.php`

Fixing that fixed my routes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but this happens when accessing the main index after a fresh install. Therefore, I have not created any controllers to add that extra space to. I am going to try another clean install when I have time.